# Как изменить шрифт заголовка QDialog?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qdialog

Есть **QDialog**  и его **title** - устанавливаю текст в заголовок так: *this->setWindowTitle("Текст");* но мне нужно сделать текст крупнее. Как изменить шрифт заголовка **QDialog**? Я читал, что это невозможно - за отображение заголовка вроде отвечает диспетчер окон. Но есть ли какие-нибудь обходные пути вроде скрыть заголовок и вручную отрисовывать текст и т.д.?

Comment: по моему это единственный способ https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/25974-stylesheet-to-QDialog-Title-Bar, т. е. самому рисовать

Comment: @PavelGridin спасибо, но так у меня получилось лишь кастомизировать саму шапку, текст всё никак

Comment: убил 2 часа на эту проблему, ничего не получается. он как был одинакового размера, так и остался, можно заклепку поставить в виде QGraphicsRectItem, который будет за окном кататься, но это не решение.